# Wordpress Base Path Hook?

Tags: wordpress, hook

What's the wordpress / php hook to link to the base path of the wordpress installation? I want to be able to link to the home page of the wordpress blog, regardless of which directory the theme is installed in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`echo '<a href="' . get_settings('siteurl') . '/wp-admin/index.php">admin</a>';`

would give you (as an example)

`<a href="http://me.com/blog/wp-admin/index.php">admin</a>`

and

`<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">`

would give you

`<a href="http://me.com/blog/index.php">`